# Restricting direct access to php file

Tags: php

I have an **index.php** file where I login and move to another file called **map.php** from where on clicking button I reach **inc.php**.

The problem is on typing the link **localhost/lilly/inc.php** the unauthorised user or any public user should not be able to access this file, only the person logged in should!

How can I do this? I have read about using .htaccess etc but I have completely not understood anything from other articles..

I have used inc.php:

```
if(!defined('MyConst')) {
   die('Direct access not permitted');
}
```

Map.php:

```
define('MyConst', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sessions`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) for your requirement.

In your index.php page, start a session and store the user id (or any other data to uniquely identify the user) after someone is logged in.

index.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id; // $user_id is the user id of the logged in user
```

And check the existence of the `user_id` in the inc.php file

inc.php:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])
header("Location:index.php"); // redirect to index.php page if the user is not logged in
```

References:

[`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php), [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)